# Cross-compile QtDbus application for Linux/MIPS

Tags: qt4, cross-compiling, dbus, qtdbus

I am trying to cross-compile dbus-chat example (included in qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2) for Linux/MIPS device. I am getting following error while building:

.../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined reference to `inotify_init@GLIBC_2.4'

.../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined
   reference to `__floatundisf@GCC_4.2.0'

.../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined
   reference to `inotify_rm_watch@GLIBC_2.4'

.../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined
   reference to `inotify_add_watch@GLIBC_2.4'

.../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.2/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined
   reference to `__floatundidf@GCC_4.2.0'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I used mipsel-linux-gcc-3.4.4 and dbus-1.0.0 for cross-compiling dbus library for QT. 
I am not sure which library is missing or may be the dbus version is not compatible. I am able to compile simple dbus application.

Comment: Have you compiled Qt for Linux/MIPS? Looks like it's not able to find the functions in your vtables for your CPU/platform.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I have compiled Qt for Linux/MIPS with Dbus. But will cross-check again.